# Drawing a box with two sides as an Arc in javascript/svg

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to make a shape like this

[image: MySketch]

and i managed to get this sofar

[image: ShapeJSFiddle]

But i cant get the right arc to go outwards instead of inwards.
I cant find any help online how to do this. I tried rotation and playing around with the rx,ry but no luck.

Here is the JSFiddle to it

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3igner/towbsczn/39/)

```
<svg height="200" width="300">
  
  
      <g stroke="none" fill="blue">
        <path d="
        M 150 0
        a 1 1 0 0 0 0 100
        l -100 0
        a 1 1 0 0 0 0 -100
        l 100 0
        Z
        "/>
      </g>
 
</svg>
```

Comment: Good SVG d-path editor at https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the first arc, you simply need to flip the `sweep-flag` to "clockwise":
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d#elliptical_arc_curve

```html
<svg height="200" width="300">

    <g stroke="none" fill="blue">
        <path d="
        M 150 0
        a 1 1 0 0 1 0 100
        l -100 0
        a 1 1 0 0 0 0 -100
        l 100 0
        Z
        "/>
    </g>
 
</svg>
```